# Need to run make twice after make clean

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

All I want to do is gather source files from different source directories into one folder and then do the build of those make files. After a make clean I have to run make command twice to do the build.

So first I run make clean, then i run make, which throws an error saying no -o files found. But when iIrun the make again, the build goes through and generates the build files.

My makefile looks like below

```
.PHONY:  dirs all clean

all: dirs $(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJ_FILES) 
    "$(CC) -rvn fLib.a $(OBJ_FILES)

# clean build target. Remove all files without reporting errors in case they don't exist.
clean:
    @rm -rf fLib.a $(OBJ_DIR)

# Build target for creating flat header file folder for SharedTrackerAPI (FLAT_INC_DIR) 
# due to too long paths in Windows 7 build
dirs:
    @echo 'Making flat source and header folders.'
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @for f in $(SRC_FILES); do cp $$f $(OBJ_DIR); done
    @mkdir -p $(FLAT_INC_DIR) 
    @OLD_CWD=$(CURDIR)
    @cd $(FLAT_INC_DIR)
    @find  $(STA_RADAR_TRACKER_IFACE) -name '*.h' | xargs -i  cp -l {} $(FLAT_INC_DIR)
    @cd $(OLD_CWD)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp
    "$(TASKING_CTC_BIN)"/cctc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

What am I doing wrong that I have to run make twice after a make clean.

Comment: Three times in the past 48 hours you have passed over simple solutions that work in pursuit of more complicated solutions that don't work. I can give you a solution to this problem but you will run smack into another problem if you don't exercise some *patience.*

Comment: @beta Yes I am trying to write makefiles from the last 2 days. Would be really great if you can point to what is wrong in the current make file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that although `dirs` will place the source files in the flat source directory, Make *doesn't know that.* Before it executes the `dirs` rule, it has already determined that it knows no way to build the object files.

The quick and dirty solution is to tell Make *"trust me, it'll be fine";* one way to do that is to modify the object rule like this:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:
    "$(TASKING_CTC_BIN)"/cctc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.cpp $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

If you stop there, you will have a working solution.

If you want a more clean, efficient and flexible makefile, you must rethink the approach to finding source files. I see no good reason to use the flat source file approach, but if you really want to use it, here is a good way:

```
vpath %.cpp $(dir $(SRC_FILES))

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp: %.cpp
    @cp $< $@
```

Now you can get rid of `dir` and use your unmodified object rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.cpp
    "$(TASKING_CTC_BIN)"/cctc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

How to handle the header files (`FLAT_INC_DIR`) is up to you, but I recommend `vpath` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the vpath solution worked like a charm, I had comeup with ugly solutions like the ones you showed without vpath, they only seemed to work, but instead made me smack into new problems. Although I have learnt something about make files, your solutions have given me a new perspective of makefiles now. Thanks a lot agian